# How to hide or adding an additional class for checkout component shipping form custom field in magento 2?

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-address, magento2.4.4

I am using **Eadesigndev_RomCity** module to populate an area dropdown on checkout. This field is rendering like below code. I need to hide it using display none in some situation.

**Since this parent div also dosen't have a class or id how can i do it?**

```
<div class="field _required _error" data-bind="visible: visible, attr: {'name': element.dataScope}, css: additionalClasses" name="" style="">

<label class="label" data-bind="attr: { for: element.uid }" for="HNF0PC6"><!-- ko if: element.label --><span data-bind="i18n: element.label">Area</span><!-- /ko --></label>

<div class="control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': element.tooltip}">
    <!-- ko ifnot: element.hasAddons() -->
        <!-- ko template: element.elementTmpl -->
<select class="select" data-bind="
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled,
    'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
    'aria-required': required,
    'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
    placeholder: placeholder
},
hasFocus: focused,
optgroup: options,
value: value,
optionsCaption: caption,
optionsValue: 'value',
optionsText: 'label',
optionsAfterRender: function(option, item) {
    if (item &amp;&amp; item.disabled) {
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {attr: {disabled: true}}, item);
    }
}" name="" id="HNF0PC6" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" aria-describedby="error-HNF0PC6">
<option data-title="Select Locality" value="">Select Locality</option>
<option data-title="Ajman Free Zone" value="Ajman Free Zone">Ajman Free Zone</option
<option data-title="Ajman Industrial" value="Ajman Industrial">Ajman Industrial</option>
<option data-title="Al Alia" value="Al Alia">Al Alia</option>
<option data-title="Al Azara" value="Al Azara">Al Azara</option>
<option data-title="Al Bahya Ajman" value="Al Bahya Ajman">Al Bahya Ajman</option
</select>
<!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: element.hasAddons() --><!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: element.tooltip --><!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: element.notice --><!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: element.error() -->
        <div class="field-error" data-bind="attr: { id: element.errorId }" generated="true" id="error-HNF0PC6">
            <span data-bind="text: element.error">This is a required field.</span>
        </div>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <!-- ko if: element.warn() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

checkout_index_index.xml file is below.

```
e<item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
           <item name="city_id" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Eadesigndev_RomCity/js/form/element/city-select</item>
                   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                       <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                   </item>

                   <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Area</item>
                       <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                       <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
                   </item>
                  </item>

                  <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Eadesigndev_RomCity/js/form/element/city</item>
                      <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                      <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                      </item>
                      <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">110</item>
                      </item>

                                                            <item name="vat_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">65</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>e
```

Comment: Create checkout_index_index.xml layout, define js file in that and using jQuery you can add custom class for any field in jQuery.ajaxComplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by using **AttributeMerger's** `afterMerge` function. Created a di.xml file under `Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
    <plugin name="customAttributeMerger" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin"/>
</type>
```

And create the **AttributeMergerPlugin.php** file on `Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin.php`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Plugin;
class AttributeMergerPlugin
{
      public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
      {
          if (array_key_exists('city_id', $result)) {
              $result['city_id']['additionalClasses'] = 'locality_fields';
          }

          return $result;
      }
}
```

After running the command this **locality_fields** class was added to the parent div. Using the class i did the hide the div task successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to hide the area field with the condition of the city field? What you can do is update the file: Magento2-City-Dropdown/view/frontend/web/js/city-update.js also.

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/utils/wrapper',
'mage/template',
'mage/validation',
'underscore',
'jquery/ui'
], function ($) {
'use strict';
return function () {

    var string = JSON.stringify($eaCitiesJson),
        obj = JSON.parse(string),
        cityInput = $("[name*='city']").val();

    $(document).ready(function (){
        var region_id = $("[name*='region_id']").val();
        var region = [];

        if (region_id) {
            $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                if (value.region_id == region_id) {
                    region.push(value.city_name);
                }
            });
            var city = $("[name*='city']"),
                selectCity = city.replaceWith("<select class='required-entry' name='city' id='city'>") + '</select>',
                htmlSelect = '<option>Selectati localitatea</option>',
                options;

            $.each(region, function (index, value) {
                if ( value == cityInput.toUpperCase()) {
                    options = '<option value="' + value + '" selected>' + value + '</option>';
                } else {
                    options = '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
                }

                htmlSelect += options;
            });

            $('#city').append(htmlSelect);
        }

    });

    $(document).on('change', "[name*='region_id']", function () {

        var region_id = $(this).val(),
            regionName = this.name,
            cityInputName = regionName.replace("region_id", "city"),
            region = [];

        if (region_id) {
            $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                if (value.region_id == region_id) {
                    region.push(value.city_name);
                }
            });
            var city = $("[name*='" + cityInputName + "']"),
                selectCity = city.replaceWith("<select class='required-entry' name='"+cityInputName+"' id='city'>") + '</select>',
                htmlSelect = '<option>Selectati localitatea</option>',
                options;

            $.each(region, function (index, value) {
                options = '<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>';
                htmlSelect += options;
            });

            $('#city').append(htmlSelect);
        }

    });
};
});
```

In this file, you can select the region id with the specific you want to select and select a city to append it to the list.

```
var region_id = $("[name*='region_id']").val();
        var region = [];

        if (region_id) {
            $.each(obj, function (index, value) {
                if (value.region_id == region_id) {
                    region.push(value.city_name);
                }
            });
```

Change according to your requirement or create a new js file to add a custom condition for any field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i followed another method. i will update it as an answer

Comment: Sure, @Mujahidh please add another answer for your solution or vote for the answer if it's helpful for you.